# Using python requests module post/get result from HTML form

Tags: python, html

I have application which pulls lottery numbers from official website of lottery.

Website allows search previous lottery games by its date.

I have tried it by using `requests` module but after request was sent I still receiving website output before submit.

Could take a look and guide me what I am doing wrong?

```
import requests
import datetime

web_page = 'https://www.lotto.pl/lotto/wyniki-i-wygrane/wyszukaj'

def import_lotto():

    date = datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 2).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    payload = {
        'data_losowania[date]': date,
        'id': 'wyszukaj-wyniki-submit'
    }

    response = requests.post(web_page, data=payload)

    with open("requests_results.html", 'w') as f:
        f.write(response.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import_lotto()
```

Comment: Is there any JavaScript involved? If it's not rendered on the server, requests won't see it.

Comment: From looking at the website linked, the results from filling out the form only come in after a POST request is made to a certain URL (check the 'action' tag on the form in the website).

What you might want to do is send that POST request yourself and parse the returned value as the website does in the javascript.

Comment: @anerisgreat Look at my edit, I have changed to `requests.post` and passed data parameters based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147914/how-to-simulate-http-post-request-using-python-requests-module but it's still giving empty output.